# Renombrar archivo de un .zip con lenguaje C

Tags: c, vscode, zip

estoy intentando renombrar el archivo del .zip y tengo un poco de código de la documentación pero la verdad no la logro entender muy bien que es que y tengo un poco de confusión por ese tema ya que llevo dos días con el tema de trabajos en lenguaje C con archivos .zip.
La librería que uso es libzip y uso solo la de zip.h, mi código es el siguiente.

```
#include <zip.h>

void main()
{
    zip_t * archive; // Aca el archivo pero no se cual ?
    const char * name = "frame.zip"; // Aca es el nombre pero del  zip o el archivo dentro del zip ?
    zip_flags_t * flags; // nose que es flags a que se refieren con eso
    zip_uint64_t * index = 0; // Y el index creo que es lo que devuelvesi encuentra algo


    // Las dos maneras como indica la documentacion para renombrar
    zip_rename(archive,index,name); // https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_rename.html
    zip_file_rename(archive,index,name,flags); // https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_rename.html

    // === Para eliminar
    zip_delete(archive,index); // https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_delete.html

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ahí va tu ejercicio :

1. Crearemos fichero `prueba.txt`
2. Comprimimos fichero creado dentro de `prueba.zip`
3. Ejecutamos script en c para que busque el fichero `prueba.txt` dentro del zip y lo cambie para `prueba.tx`

#### previos

Disponer de la libraria en c de zip en el sistema, caso contrario `apt install libzip-dev` en linux base Debian, en otros consultar https://libzip.org/packages/

#### crear ficheros test

```sh
touch prueba.txt
zip -r prueba.zip prueba.txt
```

#### mini script

```c
#include <zip.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int n, err, index = -1;
    struct zip *z; 

    // abrir fichero dentro del mismo directorio
    z = zip_open("prueba.zip", 0, &err);
    // control de errores
    if (z == NULL) {
        char buf[512];
        zip_error_to_str(buf, 512, err, errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open zip: %s\n", buf);
        return 1;
    }

    // indexar fichero
    for (n = 0; n < zip_get_num_files(z); n++) {
        const char *name = zip_get_name(z, n, 0);
        if (strcmp(name, "prueba.txt") == 0) {
            index = n;
            break;
        }
    }
    // rename fichero
    if (zip_rename(z, index, "prueba.tx") < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't rename file\n");
        zip_close(z);
        return (1);
    }

    zip_close(z);
    return (0);

}
```

#### compilación

```
gcc zip_test.c -o zip_test -l zip
```

#### comprovación

```
./ziptest

zipinfo prueba.zip 
Archive:  prueba.zip
Zip file size: 168 bytes, number of entries: 1
-rw-rw-r--  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 21-Jan-21 21:01 prueba.tx
1 file, 0 bytes uncompressed, 0 bytes compressed:  0.0%
```

Comment: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Algun punto no has hecho, o has supuesto. Pues lo estaba hacieno a la vez estaba escribiendo el post. Linux? Tienes la libreria libzip-dev instalada?

Comment: Bien, yo he supuesto que el SO era un Linux, de lo contrario no sera util mi respuesta

Comment: Windows pero la librearía zip la tengo en la carpeta de includ de  MinGW

Comment: Es muy probable que no te la haya cogido. Igulamente, no puedo responder por Windows, pues no se. Respuestsa util solo para Linux